# Insert JavaScript code using Text shortcodes without using php

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using some javascript code to show post dates and comment number in my blog, but my blog doesn't support using php codes.

My JavaScript code

```
if(showpostdate==true){document.write('<span class="post-date">'+daystr+'</span>')}
if(showpostcomment==true){document.write('<span class="post-comment">'+commento+'</span>')}
```

My HTML code to call the JavaScript code is

```
<script>showpostdate = true;var showpostcomment = true;</script>
```

I want to change this JavaScript code so if I write this text in my text box

```
[date][comment]
```

it can show the html code

```
<span class="post-date">'+daystr+'</span>
<span class="post-comments">'+commento+'</span>
```

Comment: So you want to replace [date] and [comment] with the javascript variables?

Comment: You could likely use the onchange event on the text html box. when this event is triggered you should search for [date] and [comment] and if they exist replace them with the associated html code

Comment: Give me an example plz

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jQuery library something like this would work to replace the shortcodes:

```
$('textarea').change(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  // to be more efficient I would employ a test here that a shortcode exists before applying the replace functions
  var textInBox = $this.val();
  textInBox = textInBox.replace('[date]', date); // where date is your date var
  $this.val(textInBox.replace('[comment]', commentsCount)); // where commentsCount is your comments var
});
```

It won't create the `span` that you want to wrap each variable in because you cannot nest these inside a `textarea`. If you want to have the shortcode typed in a `textarea` and then nest the returned variables in something so that you can style them, you will need to employ some kind of html + css magic where you place a see-through `textarea` over a `div` and update the `div` contents whenever the `textarea` is updated. You can then put the `span` elements inside the `div` container, and style as you want.